# Config My Domain To Point To My Windows Vps (No plesk or other software)

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vps, nameserver, configuration

I have purchased this domain -> "jsbales.com" From namecheap.com

And this VPS (full WINDOWS vps, no plesk or additional software) from CloudVPS.com

I have IIS running on my vps and I can access my website using my IP (unique and private IP, I mean to say not shared or anything)

But I am having a real hard time making jsbales.com point to my IP. (you can use this ip as an example, 37.34.36.36)

I have only used hostings from paid shared hostings from companies like hostgator.com. In which case I could simply set the nameserver like ns1.hostgator.com etc...

But I don't get how I could config my domain to point to my vps.

Sorry for asking such a noob question but I've been googling from yesterday and haven't found any tutorial. Maybe I wasn't using the proper keyword.

Any help will be hugely beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest method is to simply use Namecheap's DNS servers and create an A record pointing to your dedicated IP address:

http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/78/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I did as the tutorial tells. though there was a field called "TTL" that the tutorial doesn't talk about. It had the default value of 1800 and I left it as is.

Comment: But now if I try to go to "jsbales.com" the page says 
"Error 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED): Unknown error."

What could cause this?

Comment: EDIT: Finally got it working. There was also a mistake on my side.

Thanks a lot again for your input. You saved the day!

Comment: Glad you got it working... TTL is "time to live" and is basically the number of seconds that downstream DNS servers should cache values before needing to check your DNS settings again. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live.

Answer (score 0):

You need someone to host DNS for you.  If you have multiple servers you can host DNS yourself (but to run your own nameservers you need two different nodes to act as resolvers).

You can install the DNS service on windows server hosts to effect this, and then just add your records to an authoritative zone and slave one to the other.  However, it sounds like you only have one server.  You could buy DNS hosting from your DNS registrar (namecheap) or from anyone else; your VPS provider might offer it too.

Also, on a pedantic note, one good subnet to draw example IPs from is 192.0.2.0/24, which is allocated (along with 2 others) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting. I'll go for the namecheap suggestion though, for now.